# Spring.NET.AOP - ExceptionHandlerAdvice doesnt replace custom exception

Tags: exception, spring.net, aop

this is my first and also I am beginner in Spring.NET and also AOP.

I would like use Aspect for Exception Hadling for replacing, wrap and modify my custom exceptions.

First I defined some entity and DAO. From method Save in DAO I will throw my exception.

FYI: This is silly sample

**Entity:**

```
namespace ExceptionHandlingTutorial.Entities
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DAO:**

```
namespace ExceptionHandlingTutorial.Dao
{
    public interface ICustomerDao
    {
        void Save(Customer customer);
    }

    public class CustomerDao:ICustomerDao
    {
        #region Implementation of ICustomerDao

        public void Save(Customer customer)
        {
            throw new CustomerException(
                string.Format("Customer with id {0} already exist in repository",customer.Id));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**CustomException class definition is here:**

```
namespace ExceptionHandlingTutorial
{
    public class CustomerException : Exception
    {
        public CustomerException(string msg)
            : base(msg)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In app.config I defined `CustomerDao` object and `ExceptionHandlerAdvice` object which only replace `CustomerException` for `System.ArgumentException`.

I am not sure if `ExceptionHandlerAdvice` is auto-proxy and also I don’t how it identified targets.

I believe that it uses SpEL for define rules and when there is some exception it throws check list.
Ok this type of exception is in list some I will apply advice.

Can anybody explain to me how this aspect identified targets? For example I would like apply this aspect only for a few objects not all.

I use ref documentation Chapter 14.3 Exception handling but I couldnt find these information.

**Here is app.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <spring>

    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>

    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

      <object id="customerDao" 
              type="ExceptionHandlingTutorial.Dao.CustomerDao, ExceptionHandlingTutorial"/>

      <object id="exceptionHandlerAdvice" 
              type="Spring.Aspects.Exceptions.ExceptionHandlerAdvice, Spring.Aop">

        <property name="ExceptionHandlers">
          <list>
            <value>on exception name CustomerException replace System.ArgumentException 'Something'</value>
          </list>
        </property>

      </object>

    </objects>

  </spring>
</configuration>
```

**My main problem is that if I call method Save on DAO it throw exception type of CustomerException this exception is not replaced. Why?**

```
try
            {
                var context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
                var customerDao = (ICustomerDao)context["customerDao"];

                customerDao.Save(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Customer_1" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception type: {0}\nException message: {1}\n",
                    ex.GetType(),ex.Message));
            }
```

Thrown exception is type of `CustomerException` not `ArgumentException`,

Also I tried use DSL for defined rules when advice apply:

```
on exception (#e is T(ExceptionHandlingTutorial.CustomerException) translate new System.ArgumentException('XChange, Method Name'+ #method.Name, #e))
```

But still is throw exception type of CustomerException.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring.NET aop dynamically creates a proxy for the objects you want to apply advice to. Spring.NET returns this proxy when you do `var customerDao = (ICustomerDao)context["customerDao"];`. So *when configured correctly*, you don't get a `CustomerDao` instance, but an aop proxy from Spring implementing the `ICustomerDao` interface. This proxy intercepts the call to `Save(...)` and applies your exception handling advice.

However, you haven't configured a `ProxyFactory`, so you will not get a proxy, but a `CustomerDao` instance when calling `var customerDao = (ICustomerDao)context["customerDao"];`. You can check this in the debugger; inspect the (runtime) type of `customerDao`.

There are several methods to configure the proxy factory; I'd advise you to use an [`AdvisorAutoProxy`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-advisorautoproxy) for your case, but you can also configure it manually for each object using a plain [`ProxyFactoryObject`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxyfactoryobject) or another [`AutoProxy`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-autoproxy).

When using an `AdvisorAutoProxy`, you have to add the following object definitions to your configuration:

```xml
<object id="ExceptionAdvisorForSaveMethods" 
        type="Spring.Aop.Support.RegularExpressionMethodPointcutAdvisor, Spring.Aop">
  <property name="advice" ref="exceptionHandlerAdvice"/>
  <property name="patterns">
    <list>
      <value>.*Save.*</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</object>

<object id="ProxyCreator" 
        type="Spring.Aop.Framework.AutoProxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator, Spring.Aop" />
```

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. Now it is clearly for me :) I just created auto proxy based on type names.