# avoiding try catch code on the dao layer and catching it on the service layer

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have a service layer which references the dao layer. I use ninject's inversion control to tie the implementation.

```
public class DaoA : IDaoA
{   
    private DaoA _dao;
    public void daoMethod() {
       //throw DBUpdate exception   
    }    
}


public class ServiceA : BaseService 
{   
    private DaoA _dao;
    public result methodA() {
       _dao.daoMethod();    
    }
}
```

Now I would like to avoid the `try catch` block in the `daoMethod`. Is there a way I could catch this exception at some `BaseService`
like we do to catch `OnException` method in the `Attribute` classes in .NET?

Comment: I think this is what I need. Spring.NET AOP
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167718/spring-net-aop-exceptionhandleradvice-doesnt-replace-custom-exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you do not catch the exception in the DAO layer you can catch it in the services layer.

Comment: Is it possible to catch it in a separate class so that it avoids the boiler plate code of try catch block in every service method? Is it a good practice?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS has a way of doing it.